# queue is missing sometimes in web logic jndi tree

Tags: jms, weblogic, jndi

We are facing jndi issue.

We have four manage servers. for this servers we have 80 queues,
After restarting the server in console we have seen all queues, But after some time one of the queue is missing. In log file there is  no error.While restarting that server it will appearing missed queue.

Can anyone help on this issue...